# regular expression to split a special string with delimiters

Tags: java, regex

help me in writing the regular expression for special cases

```
input: "abc","def","gh,k","pot"
output: abc
        def
        gh,k
        pot
```

`String[] vals =   string.split("\"|,")` is not working

`val[2]` need to be: `gh,f`

Answer (score 0):

```
","|"
```

Split by this.See demo.Replace by `\n`.Remove the empty elements.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/25

or

You can simply grab the matches by using `"([^"]+)"`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/26

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a regular expression that works in full generality for comma separated files that contain quoted strings themselves containing commas is not simple.

The best one I know of is

`,(?=(?:[^\""]*\""[^\""]*\"")*(?![^\""]*\""))`

Don't forget to escape the `\` with `\\` if you quote this as a literal string in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I try this.

```
"((?:(?!").)*)"\,?
```

Grap with group 1.

**SEE DEMO:** http://regex101.com/r/yP2rC4/1

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting this right you need this `"abc","def","gh,k","pot"` `String` to be split as:
`abc`, `def`, `gh,k`, `pot`?
So, use:

```
String str = "\"abc\",\"def\",\"gh,k\",\"pot\"";
String[] values = str.split("\",\"|\""); 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
```

Although there exist an empty `String` at the beggining (which can easily be ignored of course).